# How to maintain chart size when exported to excel?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, export-to-excel, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I am developing using SSRS like this:

[image]
*I created the same report layout using Adventure works to show a detailed explanation of my question since I can't post the exact report that I am working on, for security purposes.*

So as you can see, I have the chart above and a table with a drill down below. But I am getting an issue when I am exporting this report into an excel format:

[image]
(*Report in excel format*)

The chart above is distorted by default view of the report's excel version. The chart will come back to it's original size unless I clicked the drilldown of the table (Collapsed) as shown below.

[image]
Now my question is, How can I maintain the chart's property particularly the size regardless of whether the drilldown of the table is in collapsed state or not?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible while the chart and table are on the same page. Perhaps you could put a page break between the two? In the Excel export this will put each on a separate worksheet.

Comment: create another "table" from report tools, drag your chart into it. So it wont affect by collapse/expand in another table.